# contentBackgroundAlpha has no effect on AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to make the AdvancedDataGrid blend into the background by setting contentBackgroundAlpha=0. It doesn't do anything. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alternating item colors to an empty array.

```
<mx:DataGrid contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
             alternatingItemColors="[]">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:ArrayList>
            <mx:source>
                <fx:Object data="1" />
                <fx:Object data="2" />
                <fx:Object data="3" />
                <fx:Object data="4" />
                <fx:Object data="5" />
                <fx:Object data="6" />
                <fx:Object data="7" />
                <fx:Object data="8" />
                <fx:Object data="9" />
            </mx:source>
        </mx:ArrayList>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: That did the trick. I keep getting surprised by the fact that it usually takes more than one parameter to get something working right.